# Copying folder with ignore list throws error when path is in variable

Tags: command-line, bash, directory, copy

I just want to copy a folder by omitting some content.

So that works:  copy `/stuff` dir and omit `foo` and `moo` folders inside of it

```
cp -r ./myDir/stuff/!(foo|moo) "$destination"
```

and that doesn't

```
local dir="./myDir/stuff";
cp -r "$dir"!(foo|moo) "$destination"
```

throwing error

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I'm really bad at concatenating expressions with variables spend an hour trying things with braces and some and no success

Comment: Are you executing the second one *interactively*, or in a script? If the latter, you may need to enable the `extglob` shell option (`shopt -s extglob`). You also seem to be missing a path separator: `"$dir"/!(foo|moo)` (or set `local dir="./myDir/stuff/"`)

Answer (score 0):

cp does not do regex, but you can do this

```
dir="./myDir/stuff/"
dest="/stuff"
cp -r $(ls -1 "$dir" | grep -v foo | grep -v bar  ) "$dest"
```

Break down

- `dir="./myDir/stuff/"` sets the `dir` variable to `./myDir/stuff/` the quotes are to prevent globing aka if you do this `/foo/bar *2000/` and `"/foo/bar *2000"` the first will be two arguments and also add extra stuff while the second one will be one argument
- `dest="/stuff"` same but setting the `dest` variable
- `cp -r $(ls -1 "$dir" | grep -v foo | grep -v bar  ) "$dest"`
- first `cp -r` copy, but it also copies directories
- `$(commands )` runs commands and then uses them as arguments note globing is still a thing here thats good because bash takes the spaces and newlines and uses them as sepreat arguments so files `1 2 3 4` are not treated as one thing note if you do not want globing use quotes
- ls -1 "$dir" lists the contents of `$dir` and outputs each one on a newline
- `|` pipes the text from stdout and puts in the stdin of next command hens the name pipe
- `grep -v` grep but instead of listing only the line of match it list all but the match
- `)` closing to `$(`
- "$dest" tells cp the destination to copy to note the quotes to prevent globing

I hope this answers your question i put a lot of work in to it
lnee